# Does order of data in a column matter in SQL search?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table named `dict` with the following data in which the column `word` is sorted alphabetically.

```
ID | word | definition
1    a      a's def
2    b      b's def
3    c      c's def
```

And then I run a query `SELECT * FROM dict WHERE word="a";`

Let's say I have a million row in that table. By performance, would my query run faster if the data in `word` column are sorted alphabetically or does `SQL`even care whether data are sorted or not and thus the speed is the same?

Comment: What do you mean it is sorted alphabetically?Maybe stored(accordingly to `ID`)? I don't think that it does matter, anyhow.

Comment: I mean all data in ```word```column are sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Look into *Gordon*'s answer, the issue couldn't be explained better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL tables represent unordered sets.  So, there really isn't a concept of a table being in a particular order (at least until you learn what a clustered index is).

If you want your query to run faster, create an index on `word`:

```
create index idx_dict_word on dict(word)
```

This will lookup the word in the index (very fast).  And then fetch the right words.

As for your question, you might start to get results faster if the word appears near the beginning of the table scan.  However, the query has to go through the entire table, so the ordering does not matter with respect to the query completing.

Comment: What if the query was not searching all words where it meets criteria set in the query; but only a specific word. For example,
```SELECT definition FROM dict where word="a";```

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Without an index (or constraint), the query engine doesn't know how many rows match that condition, so it has to check all rows.